# tearDown is not being initialised

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I have a Java Automation script.  I have a set up method that works but my tearDown isn't being read for some reason.

When I run my Automation test I seem to have two problems

1. If it fails the test run multiple times and the browser window stays open.
2. even if a test passed the browser window never closes, which makes things really messy.

I haven't added any feature files of code for the actual test as I think the issue is in the set up but more than happy to.

I suspect both issues are linked but I can't fathom where or how.

Here is my SeleniumSetUp Class

```
public class SeleniumSetup {

    protected WebDriver driver;

    public SeleniumSetup(WebDriver driver)
    {

    }

    public SeleniumSetup() {

    }

    public void prepareBrowserForSelenium() {

//      setup();
        if(DriverSingleton.getDriver() == null)
        {
            setup();    
        }
        else
        {
            driver = DriverSingleton.getDriver();
        }

    }

    public void setup() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Selenium and drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        System.out.println("Set up running");

    }

    public void tearDown() {

        driver.quit();
        System.out.println("Tear down running");
    }

}
```

I have added a Println and can see that this is never returned when I run my script.

Here's my Base Page;

```
package pages;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class BasePage {

    protected WebDriver driver;

    public BasePage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

}
```

And my Driver

```
package support;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class DriverSingleton {

    private static WebDriver driver;

    public DriverSingleton () {

    }

    public static WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

    public static void setDriver (WebDriver driver) {
        DriverSingleton.driver = driver;
    }

}
```

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Put the sysout in your teardown method before the line where you do the quit. If quit throws an exception your sysout will never get called

Comment: I've just done it, run my script again and the "tearDown"  message wasn't displayed in the output

Comment: I am not that familiar with selenium but depending on the testing framework you use there are annotations you can use to make sure your setup and teardown mehtods are called. In Junit there are `@Before`, `@BeforeClass`, `@After`, or `@AfterClass`. I believe TestNg has similar annotations as well. Here is an example from Junit, https://www.ecanarys.com/Blogs/ArticleID/170/Examples-of-Selenium-Webdriver-Scripts

Comment: I am using Junit and have added both After and AfterClass before my tearDown Method and it hasn't made a difference

Comment: Are you sure you're running your tests through Junit? An easy way to test this... can you run your test if you remove the `@test` annotation above it? If you can still run your test, that probably means you're not using the test runner properly, which means it won't call the methods you have annotated with `@Before` or `@After`It might help if you added code for an example test you're trying to run.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your DriverSingleton's driver never been initialized, and in `setup()` method of SeleniumSetup class, driver of SeleniumSetup is initialized and used every time you run the code , put the `tearDown()` at the end of `setup()` and your browser window will close.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Selenium and drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
System.out.println("Set up running");
   // <<------your test scenario should be placed here 
tearDown();
```

Comment: Thanks for this, we have made progress.  I have added the teafDown() to the setUp() method and the page is now closing.  However it is closing before my script runs.  now it opens and closes straight away.  Do I need to change my TearDown() Method?

Comment: Just place your test script where i commented the proper place for your code.

Comment: Remember, its better for you to use some junit predefined annotations and methods for doing these steps, you can define a method to run before and another for run after your test scenarios, these methods can help you to run your setup and tearDown steps automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try extending your driver class with junit(j5 jupiter) interfaces and override the before/after methods, here is a simple example, using some of your code:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.AfterAllCallback;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.AfterTestExecutionCallback;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.BeforeAllCallback;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.BeforeTestExecutionCallback;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext;

public class Driver implements AfterTestExecutionCallback, BeforeTestExecutionCallback, BeforeAllCallback, AfterAllCallback {

    protected WebDriver driver;

    @Override
    public void beforeAll(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Selenium and drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        System.out.println("Set up running");
    }

    @Override
    public void afterAll(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
        driver().quit();
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTestExecution(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
        //whatever steps you need before EACH test, like navigate to homepage etc...
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTestExecution(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
        // steps do to after each test, best practice is to clear everything:
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.executeScript("window.sessionStorage.clear()");
        driver.executeScript("window.localStorage.clear()");
    }
}
```